# Asp.net Core: Route Controller with Folder Name

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes

My Controllers inside some folders and when writing theirs routes, I add manually Route Attribute. like this below:

```
   [Route("api/myfolder1/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class FormulaController : ControllerBase
    {
....
    }
```

is any solution to resolve **manually adding folder name to Route Attribute** in controllers?
thanks

Comment: You are not using the root tag in the response.  So either you need a Route statement or add the root class of the response and all missing children classes to your code.

Comment: Check out [MVC Areas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Answer (score 3):

as @poke suggest, Use **Areas**.

> Step1. Move you controllers to `Areas` folder.

[image]

> Step2. Add area route to `Startup.cs`

```
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "myArea",
                pattern: "api/{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

> Step3. Add [Area] attribute to your controller

```
[Area("myfolder1")]
public class FormulaController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return Json("Helll formula/index");
    }
}
```

> Screenshots of test

[image]

Comment: Hi, @Rohullah Rajaee Rad, please let us know if you have  updated information on this issue.